# Advice on writing idiomatic Golang

Tags: go, exception, maps, associative-array

I am in the process of getting to grips with the Golang way of doing things. First some sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func logIt(s string) {
    f, _ := os.OpenFile("errors.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND,
        0666)
    defer f.Close()

    log.SetOutput(f)
    log.Println(s)
}

type iAm func(string)

func a(iam string) { logIt(iam + " A") }

func b(iam string) { logIt(iam + " B") }

func c(iam string) { logIt(iam + " C") }

var funcs = map[string]iAm{"A": a, "B": b, "C": c}

func main() {
    funcs["A"]("Je suis")
    funcs["B"]("Ich bin")
    funcs["A"]("Yo soy")
    funcs["D"]("Soy Yo")
}
```

**Explanations**

- I am channeling all my log out put to a file so I can monitor it later.  Is this the right way to channel?
- I want to identify the right function to call at run time based on user inputs. To that end I have packed the functions as a Golang map - In PHP I would have used an associative array.  This works.  However, is this an efficient way to do things.
- Finally, you will note that I don't actually have a **D** key in my map. That last funcs call causes Go to throw a wobbly.  In another language I would have wrapped those calls in a try... block and avoided the problem. From what I have understood the Go philosophy is to check the validity of the key *first* and panic rather than trying to blindly use that key.  Is that correct?

I am a Go beginner so I probably have baggage from the other languages I use.  To my mind dealing with exceptional conditions in a pre-emptive way (check the key prior to using it) is neither smart nor efficient.  Right?

Comment: The lumberjack package might help simplify file-based logging (i.e. file rotation, max size, etc) if you need something more serious: https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Logging to file

I wouldn't open and close the file each time I want to log something. At startup I would just open it once and set it as output, and before the program exists, close it. And I wouldn't use a `logIt()` function: just log using the functions of the [`log`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) package, so you can do formatted logging e.g. with [`log.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Printf) etc.

#### Dynamic function choosing

A function map is completely OK, and does well performance-wise. If you need something faster, you can do a `switch` based on the function name, and call directly the target function in the `case` branches.

#### Checking the existence of the key

The values in the `map` are function values. The zero value of a function type is `nil` and you can't call a `nil` function, so you have to check the value before proceeding to call it. Note that if you index a map with a non-existing key, the zero-value of the value type is returned which is `nil` in case of function type. So we can simply check if the value is `nil`. There is also another comma-ok idiom, e.g. `fv, ok := funcs[name]` where `ok` will be a boolean value telling if the key was found in the map.

You can do it in one place though, you don't have to duplicate it in each call:

```
func call(name, iam string) {
    if fv := funcs[name]; fv != nil {
        fv(iam)
    }
}
```

**Note:**

If you would choose to use a `switch`, the `default` branch would handle the invalid function name (and here you would not need the function map of course):

```
func call(name, iam string) error {
    switch name {
    case "A":
        a(iam)
    case "B":
        b(iam)
    case "C":
        c(iam)
    default:
        return errors.New("Unknown function: " + name)
    }
    return nil
}
```

#### Error handling / reporting

In Go functions can have multiple return values, so in Go you propagate error by returning an [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) value, even if the function normally has other return value(s).

So the `call()` function should have an `error` return type to signal if the specified function cannot be found.

You may choose to return a new `error` value created by e.g. the [`errors.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#New) function (so it can be dynamic) or you may choose to create a global variable and have a fixed error value like:

```
var ErrInvalidFunc = errors.New("Invalid function!")
```

The pros of this solution is that callers of the `call()` function can compare the returned `error` value to the value of the `ErrInvalidFunc` global variable to know that this is the case and act accordingly, e.g.:

```
if err := call("foo", "bar"); err != nil {
    if err == ErrInvalidFunc {
        // "foo" is an invalid function name
    } else {
        // Some other error
    }
}
```

#### So the complete revised program:

<sup>(Slightly compacted to avoid vertical scroll bars.)</sup>

```
package main

import ("errors"; "log"; "os")

type iAm func(string)

func a(iam string) { log.Println(iam + " A") }
func b(iam string) { log.Println(iam + " B") }
func c(iam string) { log.Println(iam + " C") }

var funcs = map[string]iAm{"A": a, "B": b, "C": c}

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("errors.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    log.SetOutput(f)

    call("A", "Je suis")
    call("B", "Ich bin")
    call("C", "Yo soy")
    call("D", "Soy Yo")
}

func call(name, iam string) error {
    if fv := funcs[name]; fv == nil {
        return errors.New("Unknown funcion: " + name)
    } else {
        fv(iam)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: @DroidOS In Go functions can have multiple return values, so in Go you propagate error by returning an `error` value, even if the function normally has other return value(s). Editing the anwser to show it.

Comment: Wow!  Now that is what I call a 5* answer.  It's like I attended a Go master class run by an expert.  Thank you again!