# Should I use log.Panic() or log.Fatal() with os.Open?

Tags: go

when we have:

```
f, err := os.Open("no-file.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()
```

I think it would make more sense to use log.Panic(err). Right?
Panic() allows defer f.Close() to execute but log.Fatal() prevents it.

Or the file doesn't get opened if not found? I supposed in that case it's irrelevant if we use Fatal or Panic. Right?

Comment: In almost all cases neither is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`log.Fatal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal) should rarely be used in production apps–if ever–as it terminates the whole app. [`log.Panic()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Panic) panics after performing the log, which again is rarely desired.

Many examples use them (or alternatively a single `panic(err)` call) to make the example code shorter (to let you focus on what the example is about), but they should be used sparingly in production apps. Instead handle the error "properly". What that means is use case-specific, you may choose to log it and return, or return a new error or do something else, but only do one thing with it (only handle it once). See [Writing good Golang code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890591/writing-good-golang-code/30891188#30891188).

Comment: Thanks but if the file cannot be found does it make sense to continue the application? From my point of view, it doesn't. Let's say we're talking about a CLI app, not GUI.

Comment: @ZoltanKing From your point of view: that's really subjective. It may be there is no point continuing the application. A valid case  may be to ask the file name again from the user, and retry.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: If this is in `main` then I think `log.Panic` is OK. If it is not, let's say it is in a method, then the method should do what it can (i.e. nothing) and return the error to the caller.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer log.Panic().

The log.Panic vs log.Fatal is essentially panic vs os.Exit(1).

Exit is worse that Panic.It also makes testing much harder.It’s much harder to deal with a code that does os.Exit.It’s quite simple to stop panic in test by the means of recover.

So, It's better to choose something that does less potential damage.